# Bscscan Verification Error

Tags: solidity, erc-20, bug, bscscan

https://bscscan.com/address/0xd9fe39eb244f5516613d1ee1c76cddbe473085fd#code

Although my TokenFactoryDef contract is verified, the contracts created under it are unverified and I cannot verify it manually. I am looking for an urgent solution, please help, I have forwarded the transaction to you.

This is the created token transaction hash

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x96dca8941f82b404cb02ef1a1a41d564e6f4eeaaab72716be28502283bf6a533

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question?
Both of the contracts are verified...................

Comment: My question is, I have a tokenFactory contract with 2 different token types.

I can't verify the tokens generated when this contract is called via bscscan, how can I do it?

@ZartajAfser

Comment: You need to verify the first contracts and later ones will be automatically verified.

To verify the first one follow the same steps. If using hardhat then hardhat verifier will work , otherwise directly copy-pasting to the bsc scan will also work

Comment: I solved the problem, because it was flattaned, it was giving other contract source codes and giving an error. When I removed them, I verified manually, then all contracts were verified automatically. Thank you for help with me <3 @ZartajAfser

Comment: Please, add the solution as answer so the question can be marked as resolved.